# Convert Arraylist to string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grep some data from a variable:

```
 Select-String -inputObject $patternstring  -Pattern $regex -AllMatches
 | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } -OutVariable outputValue
 Write-Host $outputValue
```

To the same outvariable, I am trying to do string manipulation

```
$outputValue.Substring(1,$outputValue.Length-2);
```

this fails stating that **outputValue** is an `ArrayList`.

How can I convert an `Arraylist` to `String`?

Comment: Have you tried performing a join on $outputValue first? Ala $($outputValue -join "`t")  This will give you the arraylist values serialized as one tab delimited string.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in sean_m's comment, the easiest thing to do is to simply first convert the System.Collections.ArrayList of strings to a single string by using the -join operator:

```
$outputValue = $($outputValue -join [Environment]::NewLine)
```

Once you have done this you can perform any regular string operations on $outputValue, such as the Substring() method.

Above I separate each string in the ArrayList with a new line, as that's typically the string that the -OutVariable splits the string on when converting it to an ArrayList, but you can use a different separator character/string if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$outputvalue = Select-String -inputObject $patternstring  -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
               % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }

$outputValue | % { $_.Substring(1 ,$_.Length - 2)}
```

The parameter `-outvariable` in the `ForEach-Object` doesn't seem to capture the output of the sciptblock processed ( This in Powershell V2; thank to @ShayLevi for testing it works in V3).

Comment: +1, anyway, I think you need to pipe the result to foreach in case the result is a collection, otherwise substring will fail.

Comment: @shayLevy Sure! Have forgot to paste the rigth command. Edited my answer.. again :)

Answer (score 1):

If the output is a collection of values then no matter what the type of the result is , substring should fail. Try to pipe to `Foreach-Object` and then use substring.

UPDATE:

The OutputVariable works only in v3, see @Christian solution for v2.

```
Select-String -InputObject $patternstring  -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } -OutVariable outputValue

$outputValue | Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(1,$_.Length-2) }
```

Comment: I tested this way but seem that in this foreach the `-outvariable` isn't populate. Can you confirm this issue? thanks

Comment: You're right, I was testing on v3 and it worked. It failed in v2. In any case, the result is System.String, not ArrayList.

Comment: +1 But isn't it `Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(1,$_.Length-2) }`
?

Comment: Correct again, it is fixed now :)