# why is my out-variable turning into nonsense?

Tags: powershell

I have an `-OutVariable outputValue`

I am aware that `-OutVariable` creates ArrayList object.

I can output it like this just fine, and I get the output correctly:

```
$outputValue
```

or

```
$($outputValue)
```

[image: out]

Now I am trying to send that variable output in an email body. I also don't want it to display on the console.

```
Send-MailMessage -From $FromEm -Subject $Subject -To "user@domain.com" -Body $outputValue -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -Credential $Creds -UseSsl
```

`Send_mailMessage` won't accept ArrayList variable like this. So I searched and found this post here that I can convert to string first

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23510150/8397835

```
$outputValue = $($outputValue -join '')
```

However, this is what I get back in the email:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData

Qhy is it not preserving the original value?

I am expecting this in email body (of course ignore bg color):

[image: body]

Comment: `$outputValue | Out-String`

Comment: @PetSerAl Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: @mklement0 maybe you can help with this? :)

Comment: this `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStart` indicates that you use one of the `Format-*` cmdlets for something other than FINAL output to the screen _or_ FINAL output to a plain text file. [*grin*] replace that vile, nasty, wicked `Format-*` cmdlet with the _PROPER_ cmdlet - `Select-Object` - so that you get the full objects instead of the butchered remnants wrapped in formatting code. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it is wicked indeed lol, but i swear, i am not using Format at all... soo do i Select-Object after the join? Select-Object $outValue?

Comment: @Cataster - what do you get when you do `$outputValue[3]`? or perhaps `[2]` ... try this for comparison >>> `@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -Filter '*.log' -File | Format-Table)[2]` <<< you should get red errors with `Format.FormatEntryData` somewhere in the text.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey with 3: out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely
caused by a user-specified "format-*" command which is conflicting with the default formatting. ..... with 2: 
out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData" is not valid or not in the correct sequence. This is
likely caused by a user-specified "format-*" command which is conflicting with the default formatting.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok i think i understand what you mean. this output, i am getting it from ANOTHER script into this script here and piping it ot an Out-Variable $outValue. that OTHER script has a rowobject dictionary defined that get exported as an array list at the end and piped to Format-Table. unfortunately, i cant change anything with that script, so ill have to figure out a way to pass $outValue correctly to the email body

Comment: so that is your answer - you have **_somehow_** managed to mangle your objects. it's time to back up and work thru your process to find out where the horror is butchering your objects ... [*grin*]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195890/discussion-between-cataster-and-lee-dailey).

Comment: @Lee_Dailey can you join chat please

Comment: @Cataster - i have no other ideas ... there is something "vile and disgusting" [*grin*] in the code you are working with. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i mean even if the output is a table, is it impossible to send it out in email body?

Comment: @Cataster - try `Out-String`, but you likely will need to write it to a file & then load that.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried it earlier, Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported

Comment: @Cataster - if it displays on screen, then it SHOULD save to a plain text file. try piping it to `Out-File` or `Set-Content` ...

Comment: `ps w* -ov a; $a | out-string` works for me.  Are you in PS 5.1?

Comment: @js2010 my PSVersion is 5.1.14393.2969. I think the issue is the output is a format table, which is not getting accepted as a body argument to Send-MailMessage, instead it sends it as Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndDataMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData

Comment: What is the actual command that makes the variable?  Oh, you got the answer?

Comment: @js2010 the command is: & ”script1.ps1” ”$arg1” | tee $global:logfile -append -outvariable outputValue

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers thanks for posting that link to the other post. the accepted answer helped me understand whats going on really :) i pasted these table typenames/namespaces whatever theyre called but that post never was suggested to me. anyways its delaing with more of a popup than sending a table in Send-Mail, but the solution is similar to what i need to do here: Out-String

Comment: @PetSerAl dude you were absolutely right! Out-String is what i needed! but i was supposed to assign it to a variable and pass that variable to the Send-MailMessage: $var = $outputValue | Out-String ... Send-MailMessage -body $var. however it doesnt preserve the table format unfortunately :/

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  you were absolutely right! Out-String is what i needed! but i was supposed to assign it to a variable and pass that variable to the Send-MailMessage: $var = $outputValue | Out-String ... Send-MailMessage -body $var. however it doesnt preserve the table format unfortunately :/

Comment: @Cataster - yep, the ... horrible ... code in the source script munges things pretty completely. [*sigh ...*] i would get that incredibly silly error fixed ASAP. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey is it possible to just convert the content from FormatTable to SelectObject? & ”script1.ps1” ”$arg1” | tee $global:logfile -append -outvariable outputValue | Select-Object Server,Cube,'Connection Details'

Comment: @Cataster - nope! [*sigh ...*] the _output_ of F-T is **_not a regular object_** and cannot be used for ANYTHING other than what it is designed for - final output to the screen OR to a plain text file. ///// the only solution i know of is to copy the source script to a new one, replace the F-T call with an S-O call, adjust the parameters if needed, and use the no-longer-dimwitted-dingleberry-brained version of the script. [*grin*]

Comment: @Cataster - have you tried using `ConvertTo-HTML`? looking at >>> `Get-Help ConvertTo-Html -Parameter Body` <<< it seems that can accept a string collection ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok i did this: $outputValue = $outputValue | Select-Object Server,Cube,'Connection Details' -First 3 and Send-MailMessage $outValue....now i am getting this in email: @{Server=Server1.com; Cube=Cube1; Connection Details=Connection Changed!}

Comment: @Cataster - that indicates you have a complex object that the `-Body` parameter does not know how to handle. you are going to need to find a way to convert that into a simple string. if you are sending HTML email, then i would look into the various options of the `ConvertTo-HTML` cmdlet.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so i did this: $outputValue | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table ... i get this displayed on the console: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Server</th><th>Cube</th><th>Connection Details</th></tr>
<tr><td>Server1</td><td>Cube1</td><td>Connection Changed!</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so knowing that the conversion is happening, i did this $outputValue = $outputValue | ConvertTo-HTML -As Table and passed $outValue to -Body in Send-MailMessage. i get this error: Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oh oh! wait i had to do this! Send-MailMessage -body "$outputValue". Now i can see the table in the email!!!!! other way is to just pipe the variable to Out-string :) and actually, i didnt even need to specify -As Table! just piping to cth |out-string is enough!

Comment: @Cataster - glad to know you found a workaround ... [*grin*]