# How do i wrap around select-object value?

Tags: powershell

`Format-Table` has `-wrap`, which is great when a text needs to wrap around due to console limited size or when outputting to file.

does `select-object` have something like that? if not, how can i wrap around values for `select-object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select-Object` is not a text formatting tool like `Format-Table` is. but you can pipe the output of `Select-Object` to `Format-Table`

```bsh
Get-Process | Select-Object cpu,id | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: problem with this is ill end up with another problem (i had format table but i had to change to select-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861351/why-is-my-out-variable-turning-into-nonsense)

Comment: Get-Process | Select-Object cpu,id | Format-Table -Wrap | Out-String

Comment: dang so theres no other way besides piping to FT :/